# How to get CSS attributes assigned to a html table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table where each row has some style classes assigned (dynamically through server side code).

The HTML looks like:

```
<tr id= "2977"  class ="x y z a b c" >
```

I'm using this to access the background color of a row:

```
document.getElementById("2977").style.backgroundColor
```

But I am not able to read any of the style attributes; the above line returns `null`. If I inspect the row element in Chrome, it shows me hex-color of the row.

How can I read the current background color of the element?

Comment: You should post more of the html. Since the js you posted is valid. Is the tr within a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This http://jsfiddle.net/UvYxc/ is working

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr style="background:red;" id= "2977"  class ="x y z a b c" >
        <td>RED</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("2977").style.backgroundColor="blue"
alert(document.getElementById("2977").style.backgroundColor);​
```

**Or**

```
document.getElementById("2977").className += " blue";
document.getElementById("2977").className += " red";

function getStyle(el, cssprop){
    //IE
    if (el.currentStyle)
        return el.currentStyle[cssprop]
    //Firefox
    else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop]
    else //try and get inline style
        return el.style[cssprop]
}

var el = document.getElementById("2977");
alert(getStyle(el, "backgroundColor"));
alert(getStyle(el, "color"));
```

​
A fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UvYxc/6/)
​

Comment: this is exactly what i am doing. only difference is color is set by an external style sheet file(instead of assigning manually). and i am reading it through the second line that you have written.

Comment: yes. but in my case i dont have a fixed color assigned. some style sheet class is assigning a color. and i dont have knowledge how that stylesheet is working

Comment: Then you should change the class not the color attribute. Are you using jquery ?

Comment: no i am using javascript. can you provide some more detail on how to change the class?

Comment: what if the element has multiple classes assigned.

Comment: I'm eating, will answer you shortly.

Comment: document.getElementById("2977").className += " blue";​ http://jsfiddle.net/UvYxc/5/

Comment: thnx a lot for your support, sheikh. but my problem is to read a color. i can assign it any way..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8442/discussion-between-mashit-and-sheikh-heera)

Comment: thnx for your guidance. please update your answer, so that i can mark it as accepted answer. using className i solved my problem. there were other problems that i figured out myself. but it were your comments that actually helped me understanding the thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking not to use any javascript libs you can do something like this:

```
row = document.getElementById("2977")
var bgStyle = window.getComputedStyle(row).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

I just quickly looked this up, I'm not sure if there are any pitfalls.

Comment: its giving same rgb color for every row. but for every row i have different background color

Comment: How are you looping through your TRs? How are you inspecting the value you receive from the getComputedStyle?

Comment: in a loop i am assigning classes to TRs based on the data they will contain. and i am inspecting the value received from getComputedStyle through simple alert.

Comment: You might be running into how javascript handles scope - not the same as other languages and you might need to do a little more coding to get things to work as expected.  What does your loop look like?

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to read the style attribute by using the following?

```
document.getElementById("2977").getAttribute("style");
```

Also, if you are able to use jQuery try

```
$('#2977').css('background-color');
```

Comment: getAttribute("style") is giving null

Answer (score 1):

The code looks actually right for me. Maybe with more details, I could help you better.

Comment: can you please tell what details will you need?

Comment: The html code where you're declaring the table. It's more likely that you have an error there than in the javascript code..

Answer (score 1):

Are you executing the Javascript after the page has loaded.

Try this as a test:

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById("2977").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    alert(document.getElementById("2977").style.backgroundColor);
}
window.onload = init;
```